# How to include external multiple class package in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, email, aweber, auto-responder

I would like to integrate Aweber PHP API in my Laravel (Modules Package installed). I have downloaded Aweber API package from github. -> https://github.com/aweber/AWeber-API-PHP-Library. it has a library folder in which they have included lots of files. I cannot use this in my Laravel Project. Is there any way to make it work? . I am getting error that some class not found. As include and require class is not working inside Laravel.

Comment: Use `composer` and install the package in your Laravel project. It will install it in your `vendor` directory. The autoloader will handle the file including you will be able to use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the project through composer. See:
https://packagist.org/packages/aweber/aweber

1) You should add this to your composer file "composer require aweber/aweber".

2) Write a service provider that connects the library your Laravel project. See: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers

Comment: I have added using composer, But there is no folder named aweber in the vendor package. How can I access it now